# Couchbase backup tool won't finish

Tags: backup, couchbase, database-backups

We have Couchbase 4.0.x cluster running on Windows with multiple buckets. 
I have set up full backups (via Task Scheduler) via Powershell script, it worked ok for about about 2 weeks and then I noticed something strange - cbbackup would just freeze in a middle of a task and won't move forward. 
I have a log that says it stops at different point every time. The bucket in question isn't even big - less than 10Gb on disk.
About my script - all it does is call cbbackup and pack resulting directory via 7Zip, but the execution won't reach the second step. I can provide script source if it helps.
Any suggestions on how to investigate this? Which log files on Couchbase servers should I look into? 
It seems my problem is related to [this issue](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-13386), but this one was fixed prior to 4.0 release.
**I only now learned about -v flag on cbbackup and enabled it, will see what info it'll produce.**

Comment: In the logs section there is a tab "Logs" tab. Click on the "Collect Info" button to generate a zip file with the server logs. If you do this at the time when the backup is stuck that would be the most useful. I recommend then filing a bug at issues.couchbase.com and attaching the logs to the bug report. Please also attach the script if possible.

Comment: @mikewied ok, I'll try

Comment: @mikewied believe it or not - I enabled verbose flag on cbbackup the other day and all finished fine. Dont know why

Comment: You may have run into some sort of race condition which didn't get exposed with the extra logging. If you see the issue again feel free to upload the logs to a bug and I will take a look at them.